# Redis: BUSYKEY Target key name already exists

Tags: redis

I am trying to copy a specific set of keys from a Redis instance(v4.0.1) to another instance(v5.0.5). For this I am using [MIGRATE](https://redis.io/commands/migrate) command with `COPY` option:

```
migrate <ip-address of dest redis> 6379 "" 0 5000 COPY KEYS key_1 key_2 key_3
```

There are around 500 keys and it may be possible that the some keys are getting repeated and some don't even exist in the source.

I am getting the following error:

> (error) ERR Target instance replied with error: BUSYKEY Target key
>   name already exists.

On the destination instance, I got some of the keys. Is this an error that can be ignored and can I be sure that all the existing keys are migrated?

Answer (score 0):

The `MIGRATE` command internally uses `DUMP` to generate the serialized version of the key value, and `RESTORE` in order to synthesize the key in the target instance.
That error happens when on a `RESTORE` command the key already exists. If you want to replace existing keys on the targe instance, you should use the `REPLACE` optional argument. Please revise the full optional arguments here. https://redis.io/commands/migrate#options